# JAX-RS (RESTEasy, Jersey) + Spring + OSGi

Tags: spring, jersey, osgi, jax-rs, resteasy

I'm working on transitioning of existing Java application to OSGi service which is using Spring (injections, AOP) and exposes REST API via JAX-RS (RESTEasy in particular). I was looking around on internet on how to make work this combination together, but didn't find any good solution yet.

a) Spring supports OSGi by Blueprint project.

b) RESTEasy integrates with Spring via resteasy-spring plugin. But there is no resteasy-blueprint or anything which could enable OSGi+Spring support for RESTEasy.

c) The same applies to Jersey. You can use it as a bundle or integrate it with spring using jersey-spring plugin. But not both.

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need an integration between your JAX-RS provider and OSGI library?

Comment: @Perception I just need to expose certain REST APIs. Is anything wrong with it?

Comment: No, nothing wrong with that at all. I'm asking because you shouldn't need a JAX-RS/OSGI bridge, just including the JAX-RS libraries should be sufficient.

Comment: @Perception Yes, but I need my JAX-RS resources to be injected with Spring. I'm OK with embedding internal libraries, but I don't see how can I wire JAX-RS with Blueprint in this case.